# Adding random weights to a randomly generated graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to add weights to the edges of the randomly generated graph as follows:

```
gErdosSmall = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.1], 
  DirectedEdges -> True, 
  EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{1, 5}, 10]]
```

But then is I try to get the weighted adjacency matrix of this random graph:

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[gErdosSmall] // MatrixForm
```

I get an error saying

> "A graph object is expected at position 1 in WeightedAdjacencyMatrix".

Clearly, I am missing something really obvious - what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your `gErdosSmall` did not evaluate to a `Graph`.

```
gErdosSmall = 
 RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.1], 
  DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{1, 5}, 10]]
(* RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.1], 
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeWeight -> {2.66631, 1.45058, 4.87004, 4.32779, 2.71257, 1.31485, 
   2.44376, 1.9827, 1.01843, 3.19028}] *)
```

The issue is that you are setting the `EdgeWeight` property to a list of 10 elements, but you have no way of knowing how many edges your random graph will have.

Try setting the weights after generating the graph,

```
gErdosSmall = 
 RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.1], 
  DirectedEdges -> True]
weights = RandomReal[{1, 5}, EdgeCount @ gErdosSmall]
gErdosSmall = SetProperty[gErdosSmall, EdgeWeight -> weights]
```

[image]

```
Head @ WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@gErdosSmall
(* SparseArray *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the desired result in a single step and without having to know the number of edges if you specify the `EdgeWeight` option as `EdgeWeight -> {_ :> RandomReal[{1, 5}]}` :

```
SeedRandom[123]
gErdosSmall = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[10, 0.1], 
    DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeWeight -> {_ :> RandomReal[{1, 5}]}, 
    EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[gErdosSmall] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.67966 & 1.39831 \\
>  2.88079 & 0 & 2.61296 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4.88634 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.25972 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1.50312 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.08904 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3.42299 & 0 & 0 & 3.68705 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This is great, works with `SetProperty` also to use a pattern